# Install only virsh command utility to manage KVM VMs (without GUI)

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I want to only install the packages that provide `virsh` to create and manage KVM virtual machines. What do I need to install, what do I need not install to skip the GUI elements?

For the record, I want to run them headless. KVM displays the VMs' visual output using VNC transmitting on certain ports. It would be great if someone could tell me how to know and control what those ports are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`virsh` is provided by the package libvirt-bin. If you type

> virsh<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

on the command line, Ubuntu tells you the package name and how to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libvirt-bin python-libvirt
```

This does not seem to depend on GUI stuff. `python-libvirt` makes it easy to install KVM guests as opposed to directly editing `virsh`'s XML machine configuration to create them. Refer to `man python-libvirt` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can run VMs totally headless, but then you need to set up the guest OS to use serial console.  Recent QEMU versions (post-0.14) can also route BIOS output to serial console.

See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vm-builder/+bug/302880